# Two queries and looping with Node.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have code like this:

```
exports.get_menu = function(req, fn) {
    var sql_query = "SELECT id,parent_id,nama,target,keterangan,urutan,status";sql_query +=" FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent_id=0 ORDER BY urutan ASC";
    var query = koneksi.query(sql_query, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            rows.forEach(function(d) {
                var sql_query2 = "SELECT id,parent_id,nama,target,keterangan,urutan,status";sql_query2 +=" FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent_id = "+d.id+" ORDER BY urutan ASC";
                var query2 = koneksi.query(sql_query2, function(err, rows2) {
                    if (err) {
                        return fn(false, err);
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        return fn(true, rows2)
                    };
                });
            );
        }
    });
};
```

It always results in an error.

Comment: Consider adding details such as which error you get, what you try to achieve and what have you tried so far.

Comment: error Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: You need to add that to the question by clicking "edit" button. Comments are temporary.

Comment: [this code](https://codepen.io/firmanJS/pen/WZqmMj)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 1):

You are using db query inside forEach loop and each time you call fn function which is wrong. To avoid the can't set headers error use promise or async module.

```
    var async = require('async');
    exports.get_menu = function(req, fn){
      var sql_query = "SELECT id,parent_id,nama,target,keterangan,urutan,status";
      sql_query +=" FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent_id=0 ORDER BY urutan ASC";
      var query = koneksi.query(sql_query,function(err,rows){
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        } else {
          var result = [];
          async.each(rows, function(row, callback){
            var sql_query2 = "SELECT id,parent_id,nama,target,keterangan,urutan,status";
            sql_query2 +=" FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent_id = "+row.id+" ORDER BY urutan ASC";
            var query2 = koneksi.query(sql_query2,function(err,rows2){
              if(err) {
                return callback(err);
              }
              else{ 
result.push(rows2);
                return callback()
              };
            });
          }, function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return fn(false, err);
            }
            else{
              return fn(true, result);
            }
          })
        }
      });
    };
```